# A Transparent window without the things inside being transparent

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, cocoa, transparent

I have been looking all over the internet to find out how to make a window where the window itself isn't there its just a image or a button, for example a free floating image not attached to any windows. I did find the apple roundTransparentWindow page, but it is a bit confusing and really all I would like to know is a image or bu

Answer (score 0):

Creating a completely transparent window is a multi-stage stage process:

1. Create the window using the style `NSBorderlessWindowMask` if you are doing it in code. If you are creating the window in a XIB then in Xcode uncheck all the boxes under "Controls" and "Appearance" in the Inspector.
2. In code set the window's opaque property to NO: `[window setOpaque:NO]`
3. In code set the window's background color to nothing: `[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]]`

Remember that the window will have no window controls (close, resize etc.) the user can interact with - you must manage all these things in your own code.